# How can I turn this type of dataframe into a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data frame in R that looks like below:

```
ids | A | B | C
id1 | 1 | 1 | 0
id2 | 0 | 1 | 1
id3 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

`A`,`B`,`C` are binomial columns. For instance, id1 contains A and B but not C

I want to turn it into a matrix that looks like below:

```
    A | B | C
A | 2 | 2 | 1
B | 2 | 3 | 2
C | 1 | 2 | 2
```

A-B OR B-A = 2 means that there are two ids that contain A and B.

I couldn't find a proper way to do it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication to create a occurrences matrix.

```
A = matrix(c(1, 1, 0,
             0, 1, 1,
             1, 1, 1), nrow = 3, byrow = T)

t(A)%*%A

       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    1
[2,]    2    3    2
[3,]    1    2    2
```

Comment: So first I converted my data frame into a matrix and then multiplied it by itself and it worked. Thank you